# Banner is aligned properly on computer, incorrectly on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, alignment

I'm having a peculiar problem for a website I'm designing. Viewing the website on the computer, the sliding banner displays correctly. It is aligned with the page. However, when I view my site on mobile, the banner is aligned all the way to the left on the page. I'm assuming its something in my index.css file that is either there or not there.

I have another sliding banner on my about page that is aligned on both mobile and computer. But for some reason the banner on index is giving me difficulty. Can anyone take a look for me please?

My site is EHVWellness.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Start by validating your html and css. Fix your errors:

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fehvwellness.com%2F:

5 Errors, 1 warning(s)

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fehvwellness.com%2F:

Errors (39) Warnings (29)

You have a missing style sheet:

File not found: http://ehvwellness.com/index_common_textstyles.css: Not Found

Answer (score 0):

The containing div `.container_div` has margin left/right of 'auto'. This effectively is centre align the block when there is white space either side of the block at the given width. On mobile devices there is no extra white space so the value of 'auto' is 0, the container div is pushed right up to the left of the screen, and the slider with it.

I think what you are complaining about is that you are able to scroll to the far right of the slider? This is due to some bad CSS. You have position absolute an element and are trying to control the width in pixels.

What you need to do is delete the element `#graybgnomerge`. In the CSS for the div `.full_width` add the image as a background image and position THAT:

```
background: url(sg_index_media/graybgnomerge.gif) -310px 118px repeat-x transparent
```

However the above is based on someone with a very specific monitor size. If you change the width of the monitor then the image will move left/right and you'll see the text on the logo (which is why you position absolute it, right?). As a more permanent solution, get a banner without the text on it :)